# How to temporarily switch to llvmpipe

Tags: graphics, opengl, mesa

I am attempting to figure out if a problem with fonts in Wine is related to my OpenGL driver (r600g). How can I temporarily switch to the llvmpipe software renderer to perform testing, then switch back to r600g? I am using Kubuntu 16.04 with Radeon HD 3200 graphics. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE environment variable to force software rendering on a per-application basis:

```
LIBGL_ALWAYS_SOFTWARE=1 [application] [arguments ...]
```

It only works if you are using `mesa` (which you probably are).

Comment: @Wildcard Very happy context added.

Comment: Thanks! I read about this environment variable but was under the impression that it used swrast, which is supposed to be "old and broken". But it does indeed use llvmpipe.

Comment: In case you are not using mesa (but e.g. nvidia), you may resort to using Xephyr.